# How to make an activity to everyone to see on Social Engine?

Tags: zend-framework, socialengine

I am trying to make an activity published by an admin to be visible to every member of the network, not just their friends.
As far as I could make until now, is that the table stream is preventing my message to became public, it only make a profile message. Visible only in its feed.
Does anyone have any idea how to enforce this?

[EDIT]
My code below is picking tweets in my account, I am using some settings i created (like the screen_name from twitter and the user who is publishing the tweet at the feed).
The code is doing as follows:
-> Checking if there is settings for twitter user to read its messages.
-> Save it in a table
-> Authorizing (in theory) to everyone to read this messages, ether is friend of the publisher or not.
-> Adding the activity, that I also created.

```
$TwitterUser = Engine_Api::_ ()->getApi ( 'settings', 'core' )->getSetting ( 'core.twitter.screen_name' );

if ($TwitterUser != '') {
    // Ultimo tweet postado
    $TwitterUser = Engine_Api::_ ()->getApi ( 'settings', 'core' )->getSetting ( 'core.twitter.screen_name' );
    $table = Engine_Api::_ ()->getDbtable ( 'tweets', 'user' );
    $query = $table->select ()->order ( 'tweets_id desc')->limit(1);

    $lastTweet = $table->fetchRow ( $query );
    // Set the configuration parameters
    $config = array ('adapter' => 'Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket', 'ssltransport' => 'tls' );

    // Instantiate a client object
    if (is_null ( $lastTweet )) {
        $client = new Zend_Http_Client ( "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=$TwitterUser&count=4&include_rts=1", $config );
    } else {
        $client = new Zend_Http_Client ( "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=$TwitterUser&include_rts=1&since_id=" . $lastTweet->real_id, $config );
    }
    // The following request will be sent over a TLS secure connection.
    $response = $client->request ();    
    // Pegando a resposta
    $body = json_decode ( $response->getBody () );
    if (! empty ( $body )) {
        $db = Engine_Api::_()->getDbtable('tweets', 'user')->getAdapter();
        $db->beginTransaction();

        try
        {
        $table = Engine_Api::_ ()->getDbtable ( 'users', 'user' );
        $twitter_user = $table->fetchRow ( $table->select ()->where ( 'user_id = ?', Engine_Api::_ ()->getApi ( 'settings', 'core' )->getSetting ( 'core.twitter.user_id' ) ) );
        $table = Engine_Api::_ ()->getDbtable ( 'tweets', 'user' );
        $activityApi = Engine_Api::_ ()->getDbtable ( 'actions', 'activity' );
        foreach ( array_reverse($body) as $tweet ) {
            $data = explode ( ' ', $tweet->created_at );
            $meses = array ('Jan' => '01', 'Fev' => '02', 'Mar' => '03', 'Apr' => '04', 'May' => '05', 'Jun' => '06', 'Jul' => '07', 'Aug' => '08', 'Sep' => '09', 'Oct' => '10', 'Nov' => '11', 'Dec' => '12' );
            $tweet_date = $data ['5'] . "-" . $meses [$data [1]] . '-' . $data [2] . " " . $data [3];
            $tweet_date = (date ( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime ( $tweet_date ) ));
            $last_tweet = $table->createRow();
            $last_tweet->setFromArray(array(
                    'real_id' => $tweet->id_str,
                    'user_id' => $tweet->user->id_str,
                    'screen_name' => $tweet->user->screen_name,
                    'body' => $tweet->text,
                    'retweeted' => $tweet->retweeted,
                    'created_at' => $tweet_date,
                    'profile_image_url' => $tweet->user->profile_image_url,
                    'coordinates' => $tweet->coordinates
            ));
            $last_tweet->save();
            // Authorizations
            $auth = Engine_Api::_()->authorization()->context;
            $auth->setAllowed($last_tweet, 'everyone', 'view',    true);
            $auth->setAllowed($last_tweet, 'everyone', 'comment', true);
            $auth->setAllowed($last_tweet, 'everyone', 'likes', true);
            $action = $activityApi->addActivity ($twitter_user,$last_tweet, 'post_twitter', $tweet->text);
            if( $action ) {
                $activityApi->attachActivity($action, $last_tweet);
            }
        }
        // Commit
        $db->commit();
        } catch ( Exception $e ) {
                $db->rollBack ();
                throw $e;
            }
        }
}
```

No problems happens, but the tweet that I am tracking only could be red by the user I used to publish it.

Comment: How can anybody possibly answer this? You don't give any details at all. What network? What activity? What table stream? What message? What feed? Enforce what? What code is failing? What do you expect it to do? Are you getting an error message? Please, help us to help you! Show us the codez!

Comment: Dude read at the tags before be that judgemental! You know what social engine is? If you program to the Social engine you possible should know what I am talking about

Answer (score 0):

You should create entries in stream table for this action_id.